# HLSL Integer Texture Coordinates

Tags: shader, hlsl

I'm trying to interpolate between integer pixel coordinates instead of between 0-1, because I'm using point sampling, so I'm not interested in fractions of pixels, but the texture coordinates are still coming into the pixel shader as float2 even though the data type is int2.

pixelSize is 1 divided by texture size

```
matrix WorldViewProjection;

float2 pixelSize;

Texture2D SpriteTexture;

sampler2D SpriteTextureSampler = sampler_state
{
    Texture = <SpriteTexture>;
    AddressU = clamp;
    AddressV = clamp;
    magfilter = POINT;
    minfilter = POINT;
    mipfilter = POINT;
};

struct VertexShaderOutput
{
    float4 Position : SV_POSITION;
    float4 Color : COLOR0;
    int2 TextureCoordinates : TEXCOORD0;
};

VertexShaderOutput SpriteVertexShader(float4 position : POSITION0, float4 color : COLOR0, float2 texCoord : TEXCOORD0)
{
    VertexShaderOutput output;
    output.Position = mul(position, WorldViewProjection);
    output.Color = color;
    output.TextureCoordinates = texCoord * (1 / pixelSize);
    return output;
}

float4 SpritePixelShader(VertexShaderOutput input) : COLOR
{
    float2 texCoords = input.TextureCoordinates * pixelSize;
    return tex2D(SpriteTextureSampler, texCoords) * input.Color;
}

technique SpriteDrawing
{
    pass P0
    {
        VertexShader = compile vs_2_0 SpriteVertexShader();
        PixelShader = compile ps_2_0 SpritePixelShader();
    }
};
```

Comment: If `pixelSize` is already one divided by the texture size, you should not divide it again at computing the texture coordinate. So it should be `output.TextureCoordinates = texCoord * pixelSize;`

Comment: No. 1 / 1 / x = x. Therefore 1 / 1 / texture size = texture size. I have to divide it again to get the texture size instead of having to set two variables. Multiplying the texture coordinates by texture size gives me integer texture coordinates.

Comment: Oh, I overlooked the `* pixelSize` in the pixel shader. I thought your vertex data contains integer texture coordinates. What is your problem exactly? In the post is no question and I don't see the point of converting the texCoord into integer and back to float without doing anything between.

Comment: You ask what the point of converting into integer and then back to float is? You lose the decimal value and I'm not interested in fractions of pixels as I said in my question. So instead of getting interpolated texture coordinates like: (368.4 * (1 / textureWidth), 175.8 * (1 / textureHeight)) I want it as (368, 175). My problem is that it retains the decimal value even though it's int2, so I get it as (368.4, 175.8), which makes no sense.

Comment: So I want to round down, add half a pixel (I excluded this for simplicity) and convert back into texture coordinates between 0-1. That way I always sample at the center of each pixel. In point sampling if you sample too close to the bounds of a pixel it will sample the neighbor pixel.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that you need to take a range of `0-1` and resize it to `0-w:h` then back to `0-1` later. A very useful technique for this is called [feature scaling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_scaling):

> Feature scaling is a method used to standardize the range of independent variables or features of data. In data processing, it is also known as data normalization and is generally performed during the data preprocessing step.

There are several approaches to this, but I will focus on the [rescaling approach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_scaling#Rescaling_(min-max_normalization)). Originally this approach focuses on taking a range such as `200-300` and scaling it to `0-1`. The math is simply:

[image: Rescaling]

Where `x` is the original value and `x'` is the normalized value.

---

In our case we want to go the opposite direction and scale from `0-1` back to `200-300` so we have to rework it; but while we're at it why not make it where we can go either direction to meet your requirements:

[image: customizable rescaling]

Translating this into `HLSL` is a simple task and I would recommend putting it in a common method for reuse later:

```
float RescaleInRange(float value, float oldMin, float oldMax, float newMin, float newMax) {
    if (value < oldMin) value = oldMin;
    else if (value > oldMax) value = oldMax;
    return ((value - oldMin) / (oldMax - oldMin)) * (newMax - newMin) + newMin;
}
```

---

I would leave your `TextureCoordinates` as a `float2` to remain consistent with industry standards where most use `float2` for this. Then in your vertex shader just assign it the `texCoord` that was supplied. Later, in your pixel shader you can use the rescale supplied above to work the units of `TextureCoordinates` individually (called `UV` in my code below):

```
float w = textureSize.x;
float h = textureSize.y;
float x = RescaleInRange(UV.x, 0, 1, 0, w);
float y = RescaleInRange(UV.y, 0, 1, 0, h);
return tex2D(Sampler, float2(RescaleInRange(x, 0, w, 0, 1), RescaleInRange(y, 0, h, 0, 1))) * input.Color;
```

Comment: The code I posted already does what your code does, just in a simpler and more efficient fashion. You missed the point completely. I wanted to use int2 so that it automatically rounded down, then add half a texel so that I always sample from the middle of the texel. Sampling without rounding down can result in sampling the neighbouring texel. Rounding down manually can result in a floating point precision error big enough to give a wrong result.

Comment: I thought I was being clever by using int2, but it forces it to be float2 anyway. It is impossible to do what I'm trying to do. It was an attempt to fix issues like this: http://community.monogame.net/t/gaps-between-tiles/11144/14

Comment: @Martin Simply cast each unit of the `float2` to `int` like so: `int2((int)texCoord.x, (int)texCoord.y);`.

Comment: @Martin If you clarify your post further and slim down the code to only relevant portions, and include a sample of the side work we may be able to help better.

Comment: Casting to int like that will create the aforementioned floating point precision error making the entire endeavor completely pointless.

Comment: the answer describes something so simple i'd never think to explain it step by step, but very thoroughly.

its a nice answer, but i feel if it is useful to someone they want a new career. if rescaling a range isn't intuitive the grasp of arithmetic and logic is shockingly poor.

shaders have had explicit rounding for a long time. the 'problems' with floor and ceil are nearly always a lack of basic grasp of floating point representation and how it works. (usually forgetting that constants need to become a representation)