# How can I convert world coordinates to screen coordinates using C++ and DirectX11?

Tags: directx-11, coordinate-transformation

I am working on collisions for a simple 2d game and I am trying to make sure that the sprites cannot leave the edges of the screen, and I understand how this is done, but I can't seem to get the correct coordinates to perform the calculations.

[image]

In the image, the black rectangle is my sprite whos world position is around (2.2, 0.0, 0.0) however the screen width is around ~1200. I know that I will have to deal with some sort of matrix calculation but I'm not sure which matrix I will need to use.

I have tried the following from another post on SO, but it doesn't seem to give me correct results

How can I convert my world coordinate (2.2, 0.0, 0.0) to a screen-space coordinate in pixels, so I can compare that against the width of the screen? If anyone can point me in the right direction it would be much appreciated.

**Edit**

This implementation is slightly incorrect.

I am currently checking if the center position of the rectangle is outside the bounds of the screen.

Given the following image where the world position is (-2.2, 0.0, 0.0), when this is projected into screen space coordinates, I get an X value of -76 when it is clearly on the screen, so it should be above 0. It seems there is some slight offset the more I move the rectangle around, however, at the center of the screen, the X value is correct at ~630, which is half the screen width.

Here is the code I am using to get the screen space coordinates for the center of the rectangle.

```
float centerX = boundingBox.m_center.x;
XMVECTOR centerVector = XMVectorSet(centerX, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
XMVECTOR centerProjection = XMVector3Project(centerVector, 0.0f, 0.0f, screenSize.Width, screenSize.Height, 0.0f, 1.0f, projection, view, worldMatrix);
float centerScreenSpace = XMVectorGetX(centerProjection);
```

Does anyone have any ideas why this might be?

[image]

There seems to be a 150-200 pixel offset

Comment: Another thing to keep in mind is that `DirectX-11` screen coordinates are from `-1, -1` (bottom left) to `1, 1` (upper right). Rescaling your values from pixels to this range would be very beneficial in a 2D environment; in a 3D environment the calculation requires details about the camera's position, view, and projection. Feel free to take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53591092/hlsl-integer-texture-coordinates/53764349#53764349) where I covered rescaling pretty thoroughly. However, using the 2D context should accept pixel space just fine.

Comment: @PerpetualJ Thanks for the insight, I'll take a look into this. For now I just want to get this working. There seems to be a slight problem that I have added to the OP. Would you happen to know what's causing the issue?

Comment: Are you using a 2D context or rendering textured quads with a 3D context?

Comment: @PerpetualJ The latter. I think I may have found the issue though so I will update if I make some progress.